# get_permalink() gives a certain page link only. how to solve this.?

Tags: permalinks

```
the_title('<a class="" href="' . get_permalink() . '"><h1 class="">', '</h1></a>');
```

anywhere if I use `get_permalink()` it's just giving **myblog.com/about_us**

eg: the above code I am getting H1 link as **myblog.com/about_us**

weird... how can I solve this?

Comment: please post the full code of the corresponding loop. where exactly are you using that code?

Comment: @Michael thanks for that. I've found the problem. custom structure (myblog.com/about_us) was selected in **admin panel --> setting --> permalink**. I've selected **postname** in **admin panel --> setting --> permalink** now it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Pass ID of post/page that you want to get link...

like this:--

```
//if you are in loop.
$id = get_the_ID();
//If you are not in loop, simply pass post/page ID.
the_title('<a class="" href="' . get_permalink($id) . '"><h1 class="">', '</h1></a>');
```

Comment: thanks for that. I've found the problem. custom structure (myblog.com/about_us) was selected in **admin panel --> setting --> permalink**. I've selected **postname** in **admin panel --> setting --> permalink** now it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though your loop is not constructed correctly. You need to run the `the_post()` or `setup_postdata()` function, or the `$yourquery->the_post()` method, depending on context, otherewise the `$post` `global` upon which `get_permalink` depends will not be set correctly.

Something like:

```
while (have_posts()) {
  the_post();
  echo get_permalink();
  echo '<br>';
}
```

Or...

```
while ($rand->have_posts()) {
  $rand->the_post();
  echo get_permalink();
  echo '<br>';
}
```

Or...

```
foreach ($rand as $p) {
  setup_postdata($p);
  echo get_permalink();
  echo '<br>';
}
```

Comment: thanks for that. I've found the problem. custom structure (myblog.com/about_us) was selected in **admin panel --> setting --> permalink**. I've selected **postname** in **admin panel --> setting --> permalink** now it's working fine.